# SQLAlchemy-utils: create view "if not exists"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

When I use the `create_view ()` method of the `sqlalchemy-utils` module, everything works just fine the first time I run my script. However, every time after that first call, I encounter this error :

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table XXX already exists`.

I am currently capturing the exception and `pass` to avoid my script to stop but this seems messy to me.

Is there a way to avoid that behavior ?

Comment: There is SQLAlchemy.inspect().get_table_names(), which gives you a list of - surprise - table names. You could then check if the table you want to create is already in there. However, the try:except-method you mentioned is perfectly valid, cleaner and less expensive.